# open gVim at current line number

Tags: call-process

We can open a `file` in `gVim` at line 99:

```bash
$ gvim file +99 &
```

With the same `file` open in `Emacs`, I can open it in `gVim`:

```lisp
(when (eq system-type 'gnu/linux)
    (global-set-key (kbd "C-c g") (lambda ()
        (interactive)
        (call-process "gvim" nil 0 nil buffer-file-name)
        (message "opened in gVim"))))
```

We can get the line number at point:

```lisp
(string-to-number (format-mode-line "%l"))
```

I can't figure how to add that line number into my `Emacs` call to `gVim` such that the latter opens at the same line number. I suppose it's something like this:

```lisp
(call-process "gvim" nil 0 nil (buffer-file-name +(string-to-number (format-mode-line "%l"))))
```

Any ideas how to correctly add in that line number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`format`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Formatting-Strings.html#index-format) function to construct a string from pieces. Also, use [`line-number-at-pos`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-Lines.html#index-line_002dnumber_002dat_002dpos) to get the current line numbers, which lets you get the correct number even if the buffer is [narrowed](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Narrowing.html).

```
(call-process "gvim" nil 0 nil
              buffer-file-name
              (format "+%d" (line-number-at-pos nil t)))
```